# A better way to implement a function list + switch between them in C?

Tags: c, terminal, function-pointers

I did this in my program, which I use to play with various aspects of C, algorithms and libc. Basically, it switches between functions doing various separate things according to stdin, just like if it was a console/terminal.

```c
printf("playground started\n\n"
           "where am i to go?\n");
void(*(flist[]))() = { var_m, oper_m, adv_m, error_m, preproc_m, pg_m,
                       var_b, var_ptr, var_arr, var_arr_ptr,
                       var_str, var_cast, wtf,
                       oper_keyw, oper_arithm, oper_flow,
                       oper_flow_advgoto,
                       adv_ptr_fun, adv_complex, adv_undef_behave,
                       error_scope,
                       preproc_testing,
                       coneseq,
                       ptriplets,
                       cprime_msum
                      };

#define BUFSIZE 50
char buf[BUFSIZE];
fgets(buf, BUFSIZE, stdin);

/* TODO: casting for non "void (*)(void)" functions */
if (strcmp(buf, "var_m")) (*(flist[0]))();
else if (strcmp(buf, "oper_m")) (*(flist[1]))();
else if (strcmp(buf, "adv_m")) (*(flist[2]))();
else if (strcmp(buf, "error_m")) (*(flist[3]))();
else if (strcmp(buf, "preproc_m")) (*(flist[4]))();
else if (strcmp(buf, "pg_m")) (*(flist[5]))();

else if (strcmp(buf, "var_b")) (*(flist[6]))();
else if (strcmp(buf, "var_ptr")) (*(flist[7]))();
else if (strcmp(buf, "var_arr")) (*(flist[8]))();
else if (strcmp(buf, "var_arr_ptr")) (*(flist[9]))();
else if (strcmp(buf, "var_str")) (*(flist[10]))();
else if (strcmp(buf, "var_cast")) (*(flist[11]))();
else if (strcmp(buf, "wtf")) (*(flist[12]))();

else if (strcmp(buf, "oper_keyw")) (*(flist[13]))();
else if (strcmp(buf, "oper_arithm")) (*(flist[14]))();
else if (strcmp(buf, "oper_flow")) (*(flist[15]))();
else if (strcmp(buf, "oper_flow_advgoto")) (*(flist[16]))();

else if (strcmp(buf, "adv_ptr_fun")) (*(flist[17]))();
else if (strcmp(buf, "adv_complex")) (*(flist[18]))();
else if (strcmp(buf, "adv_undef_behave")) (*(flist[19]))();

else if (strcmp(buf, "error_scope")) (*(flist[20]))();

else if (strcmp(buf, "preproc_testing")) (*(flist[21]))();
else if (strcmp(buf, "coneseq")) (*(int(*)())flist[22])();
else if (strcmp(buf, "ptriplets")) (*(int*(*)(int))flist[23])(123);
else if (strcmp(buf, "cprime_msum")) (*(flist[24]))();

// ...
```

I have a strict feeling that I am doing this very wrong. I know some languages have easy ways of doing this (e.g. python with its getattr())

So here in C must be some way to transform names to addresses, too. Sure, I can strip spaghetti if-s, strcmp-s and calls by making three arrays, first of which will contain addresses, second - function types, and the third - names, but that would be too verbosive and possibly hard to update, than those spaghetti if-s.
I could do something with enums, but they will overwrite: 1. calls to functions; 2. 2nd argument to strcmp.

Out of usual curiosity, I'd *also* like to know if there is a way to do this better in c++.

Comment: The first bit of the question starts nice and all (including stackoverflow insult directed at your inability to format code) and at the end, all of a sudden you pull C++ out of thin air. So which one is it ?

Comment: @cnicutar Not actually out of thin air. I'm learning both C and C++ at the moment - and in my mind they are quite related, given that C++ initially was an extension to C, and still able to compile C. Because that part of the question is minor, i've even marked "also" in italic, and didn't mentioned C++ in tags and the title.

Comment: I moved the code over from pastebin, because sooner or later the code will be gone and this question will be useless then. To format code, you indent it by four spaces. This can be done by marking the code and do <kbd>Ctrl-k</kbd>. There is also a small question mark at the top right, which shows a minimal menu and a link to "advanced help".

Comment: "So here in C must be some way to transform names to addresses" - nope. You have to do it yourself. Something like what you're using now, but personally I'd build a table of structs with names a fnptrs, most frequently hit at the top, and a loop (the seq from 0...24 would be a hint about that, though your 23rd function seems to be a lonesome dove with its `123` parameter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is usually named an [associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array). There is no native way in [c](/questions/tagged/c). As @WhozCraig already mentioned in the comments, you can do this with an array of `struct`s and search through that. A very simple solution could be

```
typedef void (*ptr_to_func)();
struct mapping {
    const char *name;
    ptr_to_func fn;
};

struct mapping flist[] = { { "var_m", var_m },
                           { "oper_m", oper_m },
                           { "adv_m", adv_m },
                           /* ... */
                         };

int i;
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(flist) / sizeof(flist[0]); ++i)
    if (strcmp(buf, flist[i].name) == 0)
        (flist[i].fn)();
```

With [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), you would use a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Answer (score 1):

The better way to transform names to addresses is to map the name to its corresponding function pointer. You can maintain a table to store the relationship of names and functions. To find the operation you need, you can just look up the table.

In C++'s STL, std::map or std::unordered_map can do the exact thing elegantly and efficiently. Still you can use only C and implement the same functionality yourself in stead of std::map (this is the *best* way to implement a function list + switch between them in C), but the principle is the same.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef void (*Func)(void);

map<string, Func> mp;

void var_m() {
  cout << "this is var_m()" << endl;
}

void oper_m() {
  cout << "this is oper_m()" << endl;
}

int main() {
  // Store the name-fucntion relationships into the table
  mp["var_m"] = (Func)var_m;
  mp["oper_m"] = (Func)oper_m;
  string buf;
  cin >> buf;
  // Look up the table
  if (mp.count(buf)) {
    mp[buf]();
  } else {
    cout << "not found" << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```